# why do loadings for a bifactor model differ markedly after fixing factor variances?

Tags: r-lavaan

When fitting a bifactor model, the model did not converge, The variance of for Group factor 1 was effectively zero, and the unstandardized loadings for this factor were a mess (but the standardized loadings for  Group factor 2 were rather good).

The source of this issue was the low variance for Group factor 1, which I solved by identifying the model by fixing the latent variable variances to 1 (std.lv = TRUE), rather than fixing the first indicator factor loadings.
After that, the standardized loadings for  Group factor 1 were rather good, but very weak for Group factor 2. Thus, the patterns of the standardized loadings for  Group factor 1 and 2 were reversed.

I would appreciate if someone could explain  why this is the case, as I am very uncertain if I could trust this model